# Convertir string a time_t

Tags: c, date, casting

estoy intentando obtener con este formato la fecha actual, la cosa es que necesito obtenerlo en  time_t, he estado buscando y encontre que necesito utilizar strptime y mktime pero nose como utilizarlos.

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tx = localtime(&t);
char time[100];
strftime(time, 100, "%b %d %H:%M", tx);
```

Necesito que en vez de tener el tipo char* time tenga un tipo time_t.

Toda ayuda se agradece!

Comment: Es necesario que tengas que utilizar time_t para tu tarea?, o aceptas una sugerencia de una manera diferente de obtener la hora sin utilizar time_t?

Comment: Es necesario que lo devuelva tipo time_t sino me serviria como string que es como lo tengo ahora

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. El formato time_t es un entero y poco más. Que necesitas exactamente? El formato se debe hacer después.